# Painting on mesh doesn't work

Tags: texture-painting

I can't paint on mesh, but can in uv/image editor. I believe I saw solution long time ago and cant find it anymore. Also everything work with new blend file. I probably pressed something and can figure it out what. Its not face masking.

[image]

Comment: perhaps share your file so that we can see where it comes from

Comment: @moonboots how to attach file?

Comment: for example http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: If I unclick the Mask option in T menu > Slot, and if I use another image, it works, so maybe there are 2 problems: this Mask option + the nature of your image (try to re-save it as a jpg with some other settings or different software)

Comment: I just unchecked mask in slots menu and it works. Now  I wonder how I managed to enable mask layer.

Comment: I don't remember what is this mask, I just saw that, if enabled, it won't work... is it not for projection painting?

Comment: @moonboots look like not. I don't know what this mask layer do. thanks for help anyway.

Comment: Maybe post the fix in the answer and mark it complete so that others can find this as a useful check with similar situations.

Answer (score 2):

So as @moonboots pointed, the problem was that in "Texture paint mode" ToolShelf>Slots>Mask checkbox was enabled. It must be unchecked in order to draw on mesh itself.[image]